# Undoing an applied style attribute with another class

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm designing a site proto-type with using Twitter Bootstrap.

As you know, if I apply the `hero-unit` class then it will just ignore any other color attributes in `h1` tags, and will just display them in black, because it has `color: inherit;` set in the class:

```
.hero-unit h1 {
    color: inherit;
}
```

Is there anyway to undo the color attribute which is set the in the class, with another class?

I mean apply another class like `hero-unit-fix` and let it fix the color problem.

I really don't want to modify the bootstrap css files and want them to be stock, so I can easily update or replace them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to edit the bootsrap css file, just create a class with your exception in another css file

```
.hero-unit h1.herounit-fix-red{
    color:#f00
}
```

Comment: I solved the problem by switching from `h1` tags to `div` tags. But anyways thx for your answer.

Comment: Yep, this is another way. Maybe sometimes using the right tag is important for the browser or other SEO options so..Remember what I said ;)